# Ubuntu One Deleted files

Tags: ubuntu-one

My Question is I uploaded more than 3gigs of data on UbuntuOne. then i sold my pc and got new one. after the fresh installation on new pc when i installed ubuntuone it synchronized with ubuntu one and deleted all files :/

Means PC1 - Uploaded 3gb data

```
  New Pc - Sync ~ Data gone!
```

Btw I'm on Ubuntu 10.4

Comment: Have you tried contacted Ubuntu One support directly? https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

Answer (score 1):

It might be lost because the files that you had last time in that PC that you sold were already deleted.

Comment: No. the guy using that PC has no Internet access.

Comment: ya, that might be the problem.